# Navigation up clicked

Tags: android, navigation

Previously I used onCreateOptionsMenu and onSupportNavigationUp.
Now I use MenuProvide. To check if navigation up was clicked I check id - "android.R.id.home". While it works, I'm not sure this is the right approach?

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

    addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMenuItemSelected: {${menuItem.itemId}}")
            return when (menuItem.itemId) {
                android.R.id.home -> {
                    navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                }
                else -> {
                    true
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `onSupportNavigationUp` is still what you use to handle the Up button. You don't need any MenuProvider or use `android.R.id.home` at all for that. Why do you think you need to switch how you handle up?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using menu in fragments and setHasOptionMenu and onCreateOptionsMenu are deprecated

Comment: Neither of those have anything to do with `onSupportNavigateUp`